# PHP - How to get all urls from many img's src?

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, frameworks

Let's assume we have string like this:

```
Its really great to <img src="image2.png" /> hear from you "Today is good <img src="http://www.google.com/picture2.png" /> day" Let's listen song together! ---------<img src="images/profile.png" />\\\\\\
```

This is the whole string. We have 3 img inside.

We want to produce variable from this string like

```
output[0] = 'image2.png';
output[1] = 'http://www.google.com/picture2.png';
output[2] = 'images/profile.png';
```

I mean, we have this string, and how to process him to extract all "src" from img tags and collect it in one new array variable.

How to do it? How we can achieve that?

In addition I use CodeIgniter framework. Maybe it can be done with only this framework's method but I don't see it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$src = <<<EOL
Its really great to <img src="image2.png" /> hear from you "Today is good
<img src="http://www.google.com/picture2.png" /> day" Let's listen song
together! ---------<img src="images/profile.png" />\\\\\\
EOL;

preg_match_all('~src="([^"]+)~', $src, $matches);

var_export($matches[1]);
// output ->
//        array (
//          0 => 'image2.png',
//          1 => 'http://www.google.com/picture2.png',
//          2 => 'images/profile.png',
//        )
```

Live [demo](https://ideone.com/OaQz7O)

---

**Update:** you can use `\K` in the regex pattern to get just what is needed in `$matches`:

```
preg_match_all('~src="\K[^"]+~', $src, $matches);
var_export($matches);
// output ->
//      array (
//        0 =>
//        array (
//          0 => 'image2.png',
//          1 => 'http://www.google.com/picture2.png',
//          2 => 'images/profile.png',
//        ),
//      )
```

For a reference see [Escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: Why `var_export($matches[1]);`? Why 1? Why does this produce 2 rows instead of 1?

Comment: `$matches[0]` contains array of strings that matched full pattern `src="([^"]+)`. And `$matches[1]` contains array of first submask matches: `([^"]+)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches` on the source of the whole page to pick out the src= values. Like this:

```
$src = array (); // array for src's
preg_match_all ( '/src="([^"]+)"/', $page_source, $src );
$just_urls = $src [1];
```

Where `$page_source` is your input and `$src` is the resulting array of `src=` values, and `$just_urls` is an array of just the inside of the quotes.

The pattern `/src="([^"]+)"/` will return only what's inside the quotes.

See:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: It's nice, but doesn't work fully correct. Tested this, look results here: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQFrL.png`. It's giving good results and bad results, and 2 rows instead of one.

Comment: Oh, you have to use the second array for just the matches. I'll edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PHP DOM Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). The DOM extension allows you to operate on XML documents through the DOM API with PHP.

Also you can go through below code:

```
function fetchImages($content) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $imgElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    $images = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $imgElements->length; $i++) {
        $images[] = $imgElements->item($i)->getAttribute('src');
    }

    return $images;
}
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$images = fetchImages($content);

print_r($images);
```

Comment: That's nice. But I need to do im PHP mate :D

Comment: May i know exactly requirement ? So that i can explain further :)

Comment: Answer below produces results exactly as I wanted. All clear, short and in PHP. Here: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQFrL.png` But there's something incorrect